# Бесплатная база ip по странам, областям, городам

Tags: ip, php, mysql

Посоветуйте бесплатную базу ip по странам, областям, городам. Ну можно и платные просмотреть, спасибо =)
Только желательно именно БД, а не онлайн сервисы.

Comment: [http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.geoip.php]()?

Comment: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/

Comment: Насколько я знаю, его необходимо устанавливать на сервере, это расширение не поставляется вместе с PHP.

Comment: http://ipgeobase.ru/cgi-bin/Archive.cgi вот нашел, вроде часто обновляется и бесплатная. Только в архиве файлы txt, поэтому надо написать скрипт, чтобы собрало как нужно и положило в бд. Ну думаю можно закрыть вопрос, просто не хватает уважухи. Спасибо всем кто отозвался =)

Comment: http://sypexgeo.net/